# working days between two dates in ssis

Tags: ssis

I need help to calculate working days between 2 dates in ssis.

Source is excel and destination is oracle.

Sample date :I have 2 date fields from excel source  some times date1 will greater than date date2.

```
ID | DATE1       | DATE2
------------------------------   
1  | 22-MAR-2017 | 28-MAR-2017    
2  | 13-SEP-2017 | 01-SEP-2017    
3  | 11-SEP-2017 | 4-SEP-2017
```

I tried to with similar expression in derived column ...but it didn't worked.

```
(DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1) -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done in the database by setting up a Date Dimension with all kinds of attributes.

```
Date    Month Year FiscalYear FiscalMonth ....  BusinessDay
3/22/17 March 2017  2017       3                1
3/23/17
...


Select BusDays = (Select SUM(BusinessDay) from DimDate between @startdate and @enddate)
```

I usually reserve this calculation for the presentation layer and not use SSIS. and would create a function to pass in start and end dates.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can do this in derived column, but you will have issues on finding weekdays, furthermore you have a problem when you date1 > date2.

Therefore i would extract your EXCEL data to a table, and then make your logic based on that source table. Just like my example:

**First create a Calendar Table:**

```
      SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
  SET ARITHABORT OFF
  SET ARITHIGNORE ON
  SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Script Details: Listing Of Standard Details Related To The Script
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  --    Purpose: Date Calendar Cross-Reference Table
  --    Create Date (MM/DD/YYYY): 10/29/2009
  --    Developer: Sean Smith (s.smith.sql AT gmail DOT com)
  --    Additional Notes: N/A
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Modification History: Listing Of All Modifications Since Original Implementation
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  --    Description: Fixed Bug Affecting "month_weekdays_remaining" And "quarter_weekdays_remaining" Columns
  --    Date (MM/DD/YYYY): 07/02/2014
  --    Developer: Sean Smith (s.smith.sql AT gmail DOT com)
  --    Additional Notes: N/A
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Declarations / Sets: Declare And Set Variables
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  DECLARE
     @Date_Start AS DATETIME
    ,@Date_End AS DATETIME
  
  
  SET @Date_Start = '20000101'
  SET @Date_End = '20301231'
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Error Trapping: Check If Permanent Table(s) Already Exist(s) And Drop If Applicable
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.date_calendar', N'U') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
  
    DROP TABLE dbo.date_calendar
  
  END
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Permanent Table: Create Date Xref Table
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  CREATE TABLE dbo.date_calendar
  
    (
         calendar_date DATETIME NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_date_calendar_calendar_date PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        ,calendar_year SMALLINT
        ,calendar_month TINYINT
        ,calendar_day TINYINT
        ,calendar_quarter TINYINT
        ,first_day_in_week DATETIME
        ,last_day_in_week DATETIME
        ,is_week_in_same_month INT
        ,first_day_in_month DATETIME
        ,last_day_in_month DATETIME
        ,is_last_day_in_month INT
        ,first_day_in_quarter DATETIME
        ,last_day_in_quarter DATETIME
        ,is_last_day_in_quarter INT
        ,day_of_week TINYINT
        ,week_of_month TINYINT
        ,week_of_quarter TINYINT
        ,week_of_year TINYINT
        ,days_in_month TINYINT
        ,month_days_remaining TINYINT
        ,weekdays_in_month TINYINT
        ,month_weekdays_remaining TINYINT
        ,month_weekdays_completed TINYINT
        ,days_in_quarter TINYINT
        ,quarter_days_remaining TINYINT
        ,quarter_days_completed TINYINT
        ,weekdays_in_quarter TINYINT
        ,quarter_weekdays_remaining TINYINT
        ,quarter_weekdays_completed TINYINT
        ,day_of_year SMALLINT
        ,year_days_remaining SMALLINT
        ,is_weekday INT
        ,is_leap_year INT
        ,day_name VARCHAR (10)
        ,month_day_name_instance TINYINT
        ,quarter_day_name_instance TINYINT
        ,year_day_name_instance TINYINT
        ,month_name VARCHAR (10)
        ,year_week CHAR (6)
        ,year_month CHAR (6)
        ,year_quarter CHAR (6)
    )
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Table Insert: Populate Base Date Values Into Permanent Table Using Common Table Expression (CTE)
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  ;WITH CTE_Date_Base_Table AS
  
    (
        SELECT
            @Date_Start AS calendar_date
  
        UNION ALL
  
        SELECT
            DATEADD (DAY, 1, DBT.calendar_date)
        FROM
            CTE_Date_Base_Table DBT
        WHERE
            DATEADD (DAY, 1, DBT.calendar_date) <= @Date_End
    )
  
  INSERT INTO dbo.date_calendar
  
    (
        calendar_date
    )
  
  SELECT
    DBT.calendar_date
  FROM
    CTE_Date_Base_Table DBT
  OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 0)
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Table Update I: Populate Additional Date Xref Table Fields (Pass I)
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  UPDATE
    dbo.date_calendar
  SET
     calendar_year = DATEPART (YEAR, calendar_date)
    ,calendar_month = DATEPART (MONTH, calendar_date)
    ,calendar_day = DATEPART (DAY, calendar_date)
    ,calendar_quarter = DATEPART (QUARTER, calendar_date)
    ,first_day_in_week = DATEADD (DAY, -DATEPART (WEEKDAY, calendar_date) + 1, calendar_date)
    ,first_day_in_month = CONVERT (VARCHAR (6), calendar_date, 112) + '01'
    ,day_of_week = DATEPART (WEEKDAY, calendar_date)
    ,week_of_year = DATEPART (WEEK, calendar_date)
    ,day_of_year = DATEPART (DAYOFYEAR, calendar_date)
    ,is_weekday = ISNULL ((CASE
                                WHEN ((@@DATEFIRST - 1) + (DATEPART (WEEKDAY, calendar_date) - 1)) % 7 NOT IN (5, 6) THEN 1
                                END), 0)
    ,day_name = DATENAME (WEEKDAY, calendar_date)
    ,month_name = DATENAME (MONTH, calendar_date)
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN calendar_year INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN calendar_month INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN calendar_day INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN calendar_quarter INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN first_day_in_week DATETIME NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN first_day_in_month DATETIME NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN day_of_week INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN week_of_year INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN day_of_year INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN is_weekday INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN day_name VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN month_name VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
  
  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_date_calendar_calendar_year ON dbo.date_calendar (calendar_year)
  
  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_date_calendar_calendar_month ON dbo.date_calendar (calendar_month)
  
  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_date_calendar_calendar_quarter ON dbo.date_calendar (calendar_quarter)
  
  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_date_calendar_first_day_in_week ON dbo.date_calendar (first_day_in_week)
  
  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_date_calendar_day_of_week ON dbo.date_calendar (day_of_week)
  
  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_date_calendar_is_weekday ON dbo.date_calendar (is_weekday)
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Table Update II: Populate Additional Date Xref Table Fields (Pass II)
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  UPDATE
    dbo.date_calendar
  SET
     last_day_in_week = first_day_in_week + 6
    ,last_day_in_month = DATEADD (MONTH, 1, first_day_in_month) - 1
    ,first_day_in_quarter = A.first_day_in_quarter
    ,last_day_in_quarter = A.last_day_in_quarter
    ,week_of_month = DATEDIFF (WEEK, first_day_in_month, calendar_date) + 1
    ,week_of_quarter = (week_of_year - A.min_week_of_year_in_quarter) + 1
    ,is_leap_year = ISNULL ((CASE
                                WHEN calendar_year % 400 = 0 THEN 1
                                WHEN calendar_year % 100 = 0 THEN 0
                                WHEN calendar_year % 4 = 0 THEN 1
                                END),0)
    ,year_week = CONVERT (VARCHAR (4), calendar_year) + RIGHT ('0' + CONVERT (VARCHAR (2), week_of_year), 2)
    ,year_month = CONVERT (VARCHAR (4), calendar_year) + RIGHT ('0' + CONVERT (VARCHAR (2), calendar_month), 2)
    ,year_quarter = CONVERT (VARCHAR (4), calendar_year) + 'Q' + CONVERT (VARCHAR (1), calendar_quarter)
  FROM
  
    (
        SELECT
             X.calendar_year AS subquery_calendar_year
            ,X.calendar_quarter AS subquery_calendar_quarter
            ,MIN (X.calendar_date) AS first_day_in_quarter
            ,MAX (X.calendar_date) AS last_day_in_quarter
            ,MIN (X.week_of_year) AS min_week_of_year_in_quarter
        FROM
            dbo.date_calendar X
        GROUP BY
             X.calendar_year
            ,X.calendar_quarter
    ) A
  
  WHERE
    A.subquery_calendar_year = calendar_year
    AND A.subquery_calendar_quarter = calendar_quarter
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN last_day_in_week DATETIME NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN last_day_in_month DATETIME NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN first_day_in_quarter DATETIME NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN last_day_in_quarter DATETIME NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN week_of_month INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN week_of_quarter INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN is_leap_year INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN year_week VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN year_month VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN year_quarter VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL
  
  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_date_calendar_last_day_in_week ON dbo.date_calendar (last_day_in_week)
  
  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_date_calendar_year_month ON dbo.date_calendar (year_month)
  
  
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_date_calendar_year_quarter ON dbo.date_calendar (year_quarter)
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Table Update III: Populate Additional Date Xref Table Fields (Pass III)
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  UPDATE
    dbo.date_calendar
  SET
     is_last_day_in_month = (CASE
                                WHEN last_day_in_month = calendar_date THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                                END)
    ,is_last_day_in_quarter = (CASE
                                    WHEN last_day_in_quarter = calendar_date THEN 1
                                    ELSE 0
                                    END)
    ,days_in_month = DATEPART (DAY, last_day_in_month)
    ,weekdays_in_month = A.weekdays_in_month
    ,days_in_quarter = DATEDIFF (DAY, first_day_in_quarter, last_day_in_quarter) + 1
    ,quarter_days_remaining = DATEDIFF (DAY, calendar_date, last_day_in_quarter)
    ,weekdays_in_quarter = B.weekdays_in_quarter
    ,year_days_remaining = (365 + is_leap_year) - day_of_year
  FROM
  
    (
        SELECT
             X.year_month AS subquery_year_month
            ,SUM (X.is_weekday) AS weekdays_in_month
        FROM
            dbo.date_calendar X
        GROUP BY
            X.year_month
    ) A
  
    ,(
        SELECT
             X.year_quarter AS subquery_year_quarter
            ,SUM (X.is_weekday) AS weekdays_in_quarter
        FROM
            dbo.date_calendar X
        GROUP BY
            X.year_quarter
     ) B
  
  WHERE
    A.subquery_year_month = year_month
    AND B.subquery_year_quarter = year_quarter
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN is_last_day_in_month INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN is_last_day_in_quarter INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN days_in_month INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN weekdays_in_month INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN days_in_quarter INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN quarter_days_remaining INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN weekdays_in_quarter INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN year_days_remaining INT NOT NULL
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Table Update IV: Populate Additional Date Xref Table Fields (Pass IV)
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  UPDATE
    dbo.date_calendar
  SET
     month_weekdays_remaining = weekdays_in_month - A.month_weekdays_remaining_subtraction
    ,quarter_weekdays_remaining = weekdays_in_quarter - A.quarter_weekdays_remaining_subtraction
  FROM
  
    (
        SELECT
             X.calendar_date AS subquery_calendar_date
            ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER
                                (
                                    PARTITION BY
                                        X.year_month
                                    ORDER BY
                                        X.calendar_date
                                ) AS month_weekdays_remaining_subtraction
            ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER
                                (
                                    PARTITION BY
                                        X.year_quarter
                                    ORDER BY
                                        X.calendar_date
                                ) AS quarter_weekdays_remaining_subtraction
        FROM
            dbo.date_calendar X
        WHERE
            X.is_weekday = 1
    ) A
  
  WHERE
    A.subquery_calendar_date = calendar_date
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Table Update V: Populate Additional Date Xref Table Fields (Pass V)
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  UPDATE
    X
  SET
     X.month_weekdays_remaining = (CASE
                                        WHEN Y.calendar_month = X.calendar_month AND Y.month_weekdays_remaining IS NOT NULL THEN Y.month_weekdays_remaining
                                        WHEN Z.calendar_month = X.calendar_month AND Z.month_weekdays_remaining IS NOT NULL THEN Z.month_weekdays_remaining
                                        ELSE X.weekdays_in_month
                                        END)
    ,X.quarter_weekdays_remaining = (CASE
                                        WHEN Y.calendar_quarter = X.calendar_quarter AND Y.quarter_weekdays_remaining IS NOT NULL THEN Y.quarter_weekdays_remaining
                                        WHEN Z.calendar_quarter = X.calendar_quarter AND Z.quarter_weekdays_remaining IS NOT NULL THEN Z.quarter_weekdays_remaining
                                        ELSE X.weekdays_in_quarter
                                        END)
  FROM
    dbo.date_calendar X
    LEFT JOIN dbo.date_calendar Y ON DATEADD (DAY, 1, Y.calendar_date) = X.calendar_date
    LEFT JOIN dbo.date_calendar Z ON DATEADD (DAY, 2, Z.calendar_date) = X.calendar_date
  WHERE
    X.month_weekdays_remaining IS NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN month_weekdays_remaining INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN quarter_weekdays_remaining INT NOT NULL
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Table Update VI: Populate Additional Date Xref Table Fields (Pass VI)
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  UPDATE
    dbo.date_calendar
  SET
     is_week_in_same_month = A.is_week_in_same_month
    ,month_days_remaining = days_in_month - calendar_day
    ,month_weekdays_completed = weekdays_in_month - month_weekdays_remaining
    ,quarter_days_completed = days_in_quarter - quarter_days_remaining
    ,quarter_weekdays_completed = weekdays_in_quarter - quarter_weekdays_remaining
    ,month_day_name_instance = A.month_day_name_instance
    ,quarter_day_name_instance = A.quarter_day_name_instance
    ,year_day_name_instance = A.year_day_name_instance
  FROM
  
    (
        SELECT
             X.calendar_date AS subquery_calendar_date
            ,ISNULL ((CASE
                        WHEN DATEDIFF (MONTH, X.first_day_in_week, X.last_day_in_week) = 0 THEN 1
                        END), 0) AS is_week_in_same_month
            ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER
                                (
                                    PARTITION BY
                                         X.year_month
                                        ,X.day_name
                                    ORDER BY
                                        X.calendar_date
                                ) AS month_day_name_instance
            ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER
                                (
                                    PARTITION BY
                                         X.year_quarter
                                        ,X.day_name
                                    ORDER BY
                                        X.calendar_date
                                ) AS quarter_day_name_instance
            ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER
                                (
                                    PARTITION BY
                                         X.calendar_year
                                        ,X.day_name
                                    ORDER BY
                                        X.calendar_date
                                ) AS year_day_name_instance
        FROM
            dbo.date_calendar X
    ) A
  
  WHERE
    A.subquery_calendar_date = calendar_date
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN is_week_in_same_month INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN month_days_remaining INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN month_weekdays_completed INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN quarter_days_completed INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN quarter_weekdays_completed INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN month_day_name_instance INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN quarter_day_name_instance INT NOT NULL
  
  
  ALTER TABLE dbo.date_calendar ALTER COLUMN year_day_name_instance INT NOT NULL
  
  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --    Main Query: Final Display / Output
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  SELECT
    URD.*
  FROM
    dbo.date_calendar URD
  ORDER BY
  URD.calendar_date
```

**Then you can now use your values to join on your calendar table:**

```
      DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
  (Date1 date,
  Date2 date
  )
 
  INSERT INTO @MyTable (Date1,Date2)
  VALUES
  (  '2017-03-22','2017-03-28'),
  (  '2017-09-13','2017-09-01'),
  (  '2017-09-11','2017-09-14')
 select sum(Is_weekday) as WorkingDays,Date1,Date2 from (
 Select Is_weekday, Date1,Date2 from (
  select 
  case when Date1 > Date2 then Date2 else Date1 end as Date1,Case when Date1> Date2 then Date1 else Date2 end as Date2 from (
  Select * from @MyTable
 ) x
 ) z
    
  left join dbo.date_calendar b on cast(b.calendar_date as date) between z.Date1 and z.Date2 
 where is_weekday = 1
 ) y group by Date1,Date2
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use below expression for calculating network days in SSIS:

```
DATEDIFF("dd",(DT_DATE)[Start Date],(DT_DATE)[End Date]) - (2 * (DATEPART("wk",(DT_DATE)[End Date]) - DATEPART("wk",(DT_DATE)[Start Date]))) + (DATEPART("DW",(DT_DATE)[End Date]) == 7 && DATEPART("DW",(DT_DATE)[Start Date]) == 1 ? -1 : DATEPART("DW",(DT_DATE)[End Date]) == 7 || DATEPART("DW",(DT_DATE)[Start Date]) == 1 ? 0 : 1) - 1
```